# Change channel permissions with a command (Javascript Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've tried countless different things and read multiple different documentations and always end up with some sort of error.

I need it to do these things when the `lock` command is run:

- Look for all channels which have `Send Messages` set to `true` on `@everyone`
- Change `Send Messages` to `false` on `@everyone` on these channels
- Send an embedded message into these channels

And I need it to do these things when `unlock` command is run:

- Set the permissions back to how they were on these channels (`Send Messages` back to `true` on `@everyone`)

I've tried this on the `Admin` role but it doesn't work and it doesn't do what I want to do above:

```js
if (command === "lock") {
    let channel = message.channel;
    let roles = message.guild.roles; // collection
    const adminRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Admin');

    // overwrites 'SEND_MESSAGES' role, only on this specific channel
    channel.overwritePermissions(
        adminRole,
        { 'SEND_MESSAGES': false },
        // optional 'reason' for permission overwrite
        'lockdown'
    )
        // handle responses / errors
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.log);
}
});
```

Comment: You need to show what you've tried

Comment: @Syntle I've tried this on the 'Admin' role: https://imgur.com/qThri8x

But it doesn't work & it doesn't do exactly what I would like

Comment: It'd be better to include any further explanations of your question in your question itself by editing it.

Comment: Ok I have edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're using [`overwritePermissions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions) the wrong way, this is what it should look like:

```js
channel.overwritePermissions([
  {
     id: adminRole.id,
     deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
  },
], 'Lockdown');
```

Comment: If an answer has solved your question, you should accept it so that anyone else looking for an answer knows what worked

Comment: It did solve part of it but I’m still hoping to know how to do the things I mentioned on my main post